# Android: React on alarms from AlarmManager in Service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, wakelock

I want to fetch weather information periodically to send it to a smartwatch - even if the phone is in deep sleep.
My first aproach was to implement a service, that always runs and uses Handlers with postDelay(). This only worked, when the phone was awake.

Now I have implemented a BroadcastReceiver that reacts to alarms from AlarmManager, which should fix this problem.

But how can I access the service from the BroadcastReceiver to run the actual weather update?

This Receiver is instantiated automatically, so I can't pass a reference from the service to the receiver. And I can't (and shouldn't) bind to the service, because I read, this isn't good practice. Also I don't know if the service is already up when the Receiver is constructed.

I also read, that I shouldn't run AssyncTasks from this Receiver (The fetching of the weather data runs in an AssynTask, but never takes longer than 2 seconds). How else could this be done? And: How can I use the wakeLock in the AssyncTask without risking going to deep sleep before the AssyncTask starts?

I hope you understand my problem and somebody can help me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: just call Context.startService

Comment: It is not an IntentService. Its a Service with some other BroadcastReceivers, so its constantly running....

Comment: But yes, I could create an IntentService, which I start from the BroadcastReceiver. That is a good idea, thanks.

Comment: no,  you dont have to,  ordinary Service is good enough...

Comment: But the service normally is already running. I think I don't quite understand...

Comment: a Service can be started zillion times,  no problem,  see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html, paragraph  Service Lifecycle